# How to begin text after image ends instead of displaying over image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image i am using as a background and i have a navigation bar that displays over the image. When i add a p tag it also displays over image. I am using position absolute to keep the navigation at top of page but the p tag also displays over the image instead of below.

I have tried removing the position style but it moves the navigation as well.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HLxC.png)

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sabah Khan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="background">
    <img src="images/bg.jpeg">
  </div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#expereince">Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="skills" style="overflow:hidden;">
<p>some information</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html{
  height: 100%;
  }

  #background img{

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.nav{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.nav li{
  padding: 30px 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.nav a{
  color: rgb(66,69,86);
}

.navbar-default{
  background:transparent;
  background-image:none;
  border-color:transparent;
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `background-image` via CSS and going with the solution you have above?

Comment: @hungerstar i have tried it both ways and was getting the same result. for background-image i was using cover so that the image had the same result as img tag but the text was still overlapping.

Comment: @skahn what element were you applying `background-image` to?

Comment: I was applying it to the body

Comment: So it's expected that content would overlay the image if you're applying it to the body. That's what will happen when you place elements inside of another element with a background image. Is there a reason you are not using `<img>` and making it responsive? It sounds like you're trying to implement a hero image with no overlay text.

Comment: @hungerstar Yes, a hero image with no text! sorry im still new to html and css.

Comment: @hungerstar Thank you, after i found out that it was called a hero image i was able to find resources and get the result i wanted!

Comment: Do you intend to have a responsive navigation where the links collapse into the button with three lines (hamburger menu)? If so, you'll need to change up some of your navigation markup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image`and `position: relative;`

https://jsfiddle.net/tg1vgq2o/18/

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sabah Khan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class ="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#expereince">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<div id="skills" style="overflow:hidden;">
  <p>some information</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-design-background_1048-6726.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:none;
  background-color: Transparent;
}

.nav{
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.nav li{
  padding: 30px 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.nav a{
  color: rgb(66,69,86);
}

.navbar-default{
  background:transparent;
  background-image:none;
  border-color:transparent;
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: This is good however i want the image to be 100% of the screen and not just nav bar.

Comment: For that you only have to wrap the nav in a div and assign the background styles to that div. Check the new edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the img tag and setting it to the background gave me the result i wanted!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#background {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1600/900/?image=100");
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.nav li {
  padding: 30px 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.nav a {
  color: rgb(66, 69, 86);
}

.navbar-default {
  background: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="background">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#expereince">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<div id="skills" style="overflow:hidden;">
  <p>some information</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is a bit clunky. It forces the hero to be the height of the viewport, which can change. It also allows the navigation to overlay to the top part of the image. There's also utility classes that Bootstrap provides so you don't have to what you've done in your `.nav` CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options but the simplest would be to include the image with an `<img>` tag and make it responsive with the `img-fluid` class. Which is below.

This solution also uses a regular, non-responsive nav. Which is what you included inside of a navbar nav. I'm not sure that was your intent so I pulled the non-responsive nav out of the navbar nav for this example. The second solution uses a navbar nav instead of the non-responsive nav.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <ul class="nav justify-content-center fixed-top">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#expereince">Experience</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>         </li>
    </ul>

<img class="img-fluid hero" src="https://unsplash.it/1600/900?image=100">

<main>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</main>
```

This is where you could continue to use `background-image`. The trick here is to set the bottom padding to a percentage that matches the image's dimension ratio. Here I used an image with a 16:9 ratio, so 9/16 = 56.25%, which is what I used for the bottom padding.

This solution demonstrates the responsive navbar nav which provides a hamburger menu button (button with three lines) on smaller screens. It doesn't work when clicked in this example because it needs the Bootstrap JS which I have not included.

```css
.hero {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background-image: url( 'https://unsplash.it/1600/900?image=100' );
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  padding-top: 56px;
{
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Experience</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="hero"></div>

<main>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</main>
```

Feel free to swap out the navigation types between the two examples.

You'll also notice that I've added `padding-top` to the `body`. This is so that the fixed navigation does not overlay content. If we did not do this, part of the image would be hidden behind the navigation.